# Foreign key constraint incorrectly formed 2

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I've been trying to create a laravel model class that has a foreign key, but it gives an error: `Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed`.
I know that this question have been asked multiple times, but the answers on these questions doesn't solve my problem.

My Table migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
    Schema::create('Tables', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id('id')->unique();
        $table->integer('tablenumber');

        $table->unsignedBigInteger('ReservationId');

        $table->foreign('ReservationId')->references('id')->on('reservations')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

My Reservations Migration:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::enableForeignKeyConstraints();
        Schema::create('Reservations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id('id')->unique;
            $table->datetime('ReservationOn');

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');

        });
    }
```

I'm trying to create a foreign key with `ReservationId` in the `Orders` migration, using the `id` from the `Reservations` Migration.

I guess it will be a stupid mistake somewhere, but I don't see where. (I'm still learning for it ;) )

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: is your Reservations table migration created before Tables migration? The order of the migrations is important when creating foreign keys.

Comment: @DinoNumić All right, I see it is indeed creating the foreign key before the Reservation migration is created. That is the problem I guess.
How can I change the migration order? Will changing the date and file number be enough?

Comment: yeah you can just change the date

Comment: Nice, it is working! Thank you!